# Detection of change in consecutive list elements isn't working

Tags: python, loops

My goal is to print the value of the elements in the list where the consecutive elements are changed. For instance, if the given input is `1 1 1 3 3 3 2` then the output should be `[1,3,3,2]`, because in the input you can see that the value of 1 is changing to 3, so 1 and 3 should be appended to the list, and also the value of 3 is changing to 2, so 3 and 2 should also be appended to the list.

The required output is `[1,3,3,2]`.
However, my code is returning only `[1,3]` but not `[3,2]`. I don't understand why?

```
for t in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]
    l=[]
    if a.count(a[0])==len(a):
        print("0")
    else:
        for i in a:
            if a[i] != a[i+1]:
                print(i)
                l.extend((a[i],a[i+1]))
        print(l)
```

Comment: Why `[1,3,3,2]`? What about the 2 at the end of the original list? Shouldn't it be `[1,3,3,2,2,1]`?

Comment: @MrGeek no i want the values in a new list where the consecutive values of the given output are changing - i mean given input is 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 here you can see that the value of 1 changing to 3, so 1 and 3 should be appended to another list and also the value of 3 changing to 2 so 3 and 2 should also be appended to the list

Comment: Not very clear from the question, you should probably add this explanation.

Comment: @MrGeek yeah i have done so far and explained in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2]
output = []
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] != a[i + 1]:
        output.append(a[i])
        output.append(a[i+1])

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for i in a` will iterate the *values* in `a`, not the *indices*. That is why you get unexpected results, and could even run into an error.

You can use `zip` to get two consecutive values, and then you turn this into a list comprehension:

```
a = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2]
l = [k 
     for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]) 
         for k in (i, j) 
             if i != j]
```

Comment: While that one-liner certainly fits on a single line, it's not at all suitable as an answer for OP... and I wouldn't let it fly in a "_real_" codebase either...

Comment: @Attie I have to disagree. This is an effective use of zipping and filtering, would require little modification to deal with a stream (which is often needed for this sort of edge detection), and he competently explains what the OP's actual misunderstanding was. This is a good answer. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be production-worthy.

Comment: "_effective use of zipping and filtering_" - agreed... but it's unreadable on first glance and without a deep understanding of the language (e.g: which of those `for` loops is the outer?). It would be much easier to follow if it was over multiple lines.

Comment: @Attie, I put it on several lines for you. This is BTW not an attempt to write one-liners, but to write code according to the *functional programming* paradigm, just as your solution also does, but with the use of `itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to @trincot's answer, you can achieve the same thing more clearly / explicitly, as follows:

```py
from itertools import chain

# input data
a = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2]

# get a list of all pairs ( N , N+1 )
pairs = zip(a, a[1:])

# filter the list, keeping only the changes
changes = filter(lambda v: v[0] != v[1], pairs)

# flatten the retained changes into a simple list
l = [ *chain.from_iterable(changes) ]
```

*Note:* `chain.from_iterable()` will convert `[(1, 3), (3, 2)]` into the desired `[1, 3, 3, 2]`.